# PHP: How to make all arrays have the same keys

Tags: php, arrays

currently, I try to perform a scrapping in a web site that comes with different shapes of information.

The final result I need to be a CSV file. The problem is that pages with different page shapes need different fields.

Let's say, after the scrapping, I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array(
        'key-1' => 'value #1',
        'key-2' => 'value #2',
        'key-3' => 'value #3',
    ),
    [2] => Array(
        'key-2' => 'value #2',
        'key-3' => 'value #3',
    ),
    [3] => Array(
        'key-1' => 'value #1',
        'key-3' => 'value #3',
    ),
    [4] => Array(
        'key-2' => 'value #2',
    ),
)
```

So, how can I make this array looks like the following one?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array(
        'key-1' => 'value #1',
        'key-2' => 'value #2',
        'key-3' => 'value #3',
    ),
    [2] => Array(
        'key-1' =>
        'key-2' => 'value #2',
        'key-3' => 'value #3',
    ),
    [3] => Array(
        'key-1' => 'value #1',
        'key-2' =>
        'key-3' => 'value #3',
    ),
    [4] => Array(
        'key-1' =>
        'key-2' => 'value #2'
        'key-3' =>
    ),
)
```

Is there any possible way? Keep in mind that each of the tables is going to have something like 20 keys and the final array is going to have ~2000 items.

Actually, I am looking for the best performant solution in order to avoid crash my computer while it is trying to process the data.

**UPDATE #1:** *The missing keys are not known from the beginning. Almost each product has different fields, and only a few are the same for each of the available products.*

**UPDATE #2:** *This is a possible sample output of the CSV*

```
key-1,key-2,key-3
value #1,value #2,value #3
,value #2,value #3
value #1,,value #3
,value #2,
```

Comment: You don't need to add values to array. Just add empty values when writing to a csv.

Comment: There is no magic. Just use a for loop. `for( $x = 1; $x <= 20; $x++ )`

Comment: @u_mulder The thing is that I don't know the missing keys from the beginning. Almost each product I try to scrap has different keys. Only few are the same for each product.

Comment: do you know that max keys will be 20 only and what are those 20 keys ?

Comment: @Naincy unfortunately not. I don't know the number of keys required for each of the products from the begenning.

Comment: can you share the sample csv format  in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full solution is:

```
// your source array
$a = Array
(
    Array(
        'key-1' => 'value #1',
        'key-2' => 'value #2',
        'key-3' => 'value #3',
    ),
    Array(
        'key-2' => 'value #2',
        'key-3' => 'value #3',
    ),
    Array(
        'key-1' => 'value #1',
        'key-3' => 'value #3',
    ),
    Array(
        'key-2' => 'value #2',
    ),
);

// storage for keys
$keys = [];

foreach ($a as $row) {
    // keys of current row
    $current_keys = array_keys($row);
    // find keys that are not already in a `$keys`
    $diff = array_diff($current_keys, $keys);

    // if keys found - add them to `$keys`
    if ($diff) {
        $keys = array_merge($keys, $diff);
    }

}

echo'<pre>',print_r($keys),'</pre>';    // check values of keys

foreach ($a as $row) {
    $rowForCsv = [];
    // check what keys exist in current `$row`
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $rowForCsv[$key] = !empty($row[$key]) ? $row[$key] : '';
    }
    // add `$rowForCsv` to CSV file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $first_element = array_keys( $array[0] );
   foreach($array as &$item)
   {
            foreach($first_element as $key)
            {
                     if(!array_key_exists($key, $item))
                     {
                              $item[$key]='';
                     }
            }
            ksort($item);
   }
   unset($item);
   print_r($array);
?>
```

**Test results**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
<?php


$array = array
(
    array(
        'key-1' => 'value #1',
        'key-2' => 'value #2',
        'key-3' => 'value #3',
    ),
    array(
        'key-2' => 'value #2',
        'key-3' => 'value #3',
    ),
    array(
        'key-1' => 'value #1',
        'key-3' => 'value #3',
    ),
    array(
        'key-2' => 'value #2',
    ),
);

   $first_element = array_keys( $array[0] );
   foreach($array as &$item)
   {
            foreach($first_element as $key)
            {
                     if(!array_key_exists($key, $item))
                     {
                              $item[$key]='';
                     }
            }
        ksort($item);
   }
   unset($item);
   print_r($array);

?>
```

***Output***

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key-1] => value #1
            [key-2] => value #2
            [key-3] => value #3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key-1] => 
            [key-2] => value #2
            [key-3] => value #3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key-1] => value #1
            [key-2] => 
            [key-3] => value #3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [key-1] => 
            [key-2] => value #2
            [key-3] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope my simplest post will also be helpful. Here we are using `array_map`, `array_keys`, `array_merge_recursive` , `array_diff` and `splat` operator.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/852348)

```
$allKeys=  array_map('array_keys', $array);//getting all keys of complete array
$result=array_unique(array_merge_recursive(...$allKeys));//getting unique keys
foreach ($array as $key => &$value){
    $data=array_diff($result, array_keys($value));//remaining keys
    if(count($data)!=0)
    {
        $newData=array();
        foreach($result as $key => $resultValue)
        {
            $newData[$resultValue]=isset($value[$resultValue]) ? $value[$resultValue] : "";
        }
        $value=$newData;//filled new data with absent keys
    }
}
print_r($array);
```